# WebRTC how STUN server feedbacks the SDP and ICE candidates?

Tags: javascript, html, p2p, webrtc, stun

I'm testing WebRTC procedure step by step for my sake.

I wrote some testing site for server-less WebRTC.

http://webrtcdevelop.appspot.com/

In fact, STUN server by google is used, but no signalling server deployed.

Session Description Protocol (SDP) is exchanged manually by hand that is CopyPaste between browser windows.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

So far, here is the result I've got with the code:

```
'use strict';

var peerCon;
var ch;

$(document)
    .ready(function()
    {
        init();

        $('#remotebtn2')
            .attr("disabled", "");

        $('#localbtn')
            .click(function()
            {
                offerCreate();

                $('#localbtn')
                    .attr("disabled", "");
                $('#remotebtn')
                    .attr("disabled", "");

                $('#remotebtn2')
                    .removeAttr("disabled");
            });

        $('#remotebtn')
            .click(function()
            {
                answerCreate(
                    new RTCSessionDescription(JSON.parse($('#remote')
                        .val())));

                $('#localbtn')
                    .attr("disabled", "");
                $('#remotebtn')
                    .attr("disabled", "");

                $('#remotebtn')
                    .attr("disabled", "");
            });

        $('#remotebtn2')
            .click(function()
            {
                answerGet(
                    new RTCSessionDescription(JSON.parse($('#remote')
                        .val())));

                $('#remotebtn2')
                    .attr("disabled", "");
            });
    });


var init = function()
{
    //offer------
    peerCon =
        new RTCPeerConnection(
        {
            "iceServers": [
            {
                "url": "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"
            }]
        },
        {
            "optional": [
            {
                "RtpDataChannels": true
            }]
        });

    peerCon.onicecandidate = function(e)
    {
        console.log(e);
    };

    ch = peerCon.createDataChannel(
        'ch1',
        {
            reliable: false
        });
    ch.onopen = function()
    {
        alert('ch.onopen');
        ch.send("hello chat!");
    };
    ch.onmessage = function(e)
    {
        alert(e.data);
    };


};

var offerCreate = function()
{
    peerCon
        .createOffer(function(description)
        {
            peerCon
                .setLocalDescription(description, function()
                {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(description));
                    $('#local')
                        .text(JSON.stringify(description));
                }, error);
        }, error);

};

var answerCreate = function(descreption)
{
    peerCon
        .setRemoteDescription(descreption, function()
        {
            peerCon
                .createAnswer(
                    function(description)
                    {
                        peerCon
                            .setLocalDescription(description, function()
                            {
                                console.log(JSON.stringify(description));
                                $('#local')
                                    .text(JSON.stringify(description));

                            }, error);
                    }, error);
        }, error);

};
var answerGet = function(description)
{
    peerCon.setRemoteDescription(description, function()
    { //
        console.log(JSON.stringify(description));
        alert('local-remote-setDescriptions complete!');
    }, error);
};

var error = function(e)
{
    console.log(e);
};
```

- Firefox(26.0):
  `RtpDataChannels` 
  `onopen` event is fired successfully, but `send` fails.
- Chrome(31.0):
  `RtpDataChannels` 
  `onopen` event is not fired.

So, my question is,

I want to know why Chrome fails on `RtpDataChannels` 
`onopen` event, and how to fix.

Probably more importantly, I want to understand how to manage ICE `.onicecandidate` event.

The Offer Local Description fed-back from STUN server is, for instance. as follows:

```
{"sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 7430372191078664219 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE audio data\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS\r\nm=audio 1 RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 0 8 106 105 13 126\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:1 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:Gj7WBxZNS7HswoxM\r\na=ice-pwd:FsXen3Tz2sXdXV31splr7WKg\r\na=ice-options:google-ice\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 EF:67:28:00:41:B6:08:A3:C5:27:BF:38:84:83:CF:8D:DC:CC:95:A9:6C:DB:77:44:DA:B2:D1:05:39:73:99:D1\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:audio\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=recvonly\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=crypto:1 AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_80 inline:ZTGRIJAdH3o1Y1T/6gF3YUtCF5CTdsaEkjWCtWJ+\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10\r\na=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000\r\na=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=rtpmap:106 CN/32000\r\na=rtpmap:105 CN/16000\r\na=rtpmap:13 CN/8000\r\na=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000\r\na=maxptime:60\r\nm=application 1 RTP/SAVPF 101\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:1 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:Gj7WBxZNS7HswoxM\r\na=ice-pwd:FsXen3Tz2sXdXV31splr7WKg\r\na=ice-options:google-ice\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 EF:67:28:00:41:B6:08:A3:C5:27:BF:38:84:83:CF:8D:DC:CC:95:A9:6C:DB:77:44:DA:B2:D1:05:39:73:99:D1\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:data\r\na=sendrecv\r\nb=AS:30\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=crypto:1 AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_80 inline:ZTGRIJAdH3o1Y1T/6gF3YUtCF5CTdsaEkjWCtWJ+\r\na=rtpmap:101 google-data/90000\r\na=ssrc:3757983348 cname:ojw6/osqSDh7tsMo\r\na=ssrc:3757983348 msid:ch1 ch1\r\na=ssrc:3757983348 mslabel:ch1\r\na=ssrc:3757983348 label:ch1\r\n","type":"offer"}
```

The only IP I could see is `127.0.0.1` that is the `localhost`, but I suppose some global address should be included in SDP info because without it, we can connect only locally.

So, I guess I need to marge the various ICE candidates onicecaditate event with SDP, but I'm not sure how, and I think this issue is related to the failure of the test.

Any suggestion and recommendation to read is appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Ok, probably, this is the same topic I'm following right now:

> necessary to send ice candidates across, or do they come packaged in offer/answer data?
>   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/UOnopWJ1l44

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> necessary to send ice candidates across, or do they come packaged in offer/answer data? >https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/UOnopWJ1l44

Chrome send ICE candidates independently arrives aside from the initial SDP package, and while ICE candidates arrived, they automatically marge into /update  the LocalDescription.

So, need to wait the completion of the series ICE candidates, that is marked with a null ICE candidate object, then output/send-to-signalling server.

Having the modification of the code with the above discovery, now the situation changes:
Please see my next question for the detail. (so far unresolved 2013/12/17)

[WebRTC SDP object (local description) by Firefox does not contain DataChannel info unlike Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622748/webrtc-sdp-object-local-description-by-firefox-does-not-contain-datachannel-in)