# WebRTC SDP object (local description) by Firefox does not contain DataChannel info unlike Chrome?

Tags: html, webrtc

I'm testing WebRTC procedure step by step for my sake.

I wrote some testing site for server-less WebRTC.

http://webrtcdevelop.appspot.com/

In fact, STUN server by google is used, but no signalling server deployed.

Session Description Protocol (SDP) is exchanged manually by hand that is CopyPaste between browser windows.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

So far, here is the result I've got with the code:

```
'use strict';

var peerCon;
var ch;

$(document)
    .ready(function()
    {
        init();

        $('#remotebtn2')
            .attr("disabled", "");

        $('#localbtn')
            .click(function()
            {
                offerCreate();

                $('#localbtn')
                    .attr("disabled", "");
                $('#remotebtn')
                    .attr("disabled", "");

                $('#remotebtn2')
                    .removeAttr("disabled");
            });

        $('#remotebtn')
            .click(function()
            {
                answerCreate(
                    new RTCSessionDescription(JSON.parse($('#remote')
                        .val())));

                $('#localbtn')
                    .attr("disabled", "");
                $('#remotebtn')
                    .attr("disabled", "");

                $('#remotebtn')
                    .attr("disabled", "");
            });

        $('#remotebtn2')
            .click(function()
            {
                answerGet(
                    new RTCSessionDescription(JSON.parse($('#remote')
                        .val())));

                $('#remotebtn2')
                    .attr("disabled", "");
            });
        $('#msgbtn')
            .click(function()
            {
                msgSend($('#msg')
                    .val());

            });
    });

var init = function()
{
    //offer------
    peerCon =
        new RTCPeerConnection(
        {
            "iceServers": [
            {
                "url": "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"
            }]
        },
        {
            "optional": []
        });

    var localDescriptionOut = function()
    {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(peerCon.localDescription));
        $('#local')
            .text(JSON.stringify(peerCon.localDescription));


    };

    peerCon.onicecandidate = function(e)
    {
        console.log(e);

        if (e.candidate === null)
        {
            console.log('candidate empty!');
            localDescriptionOut();
        }
    };

    ch = peerCon.createDataChannel(
        'ch1',
        {
            reliable: true
        });
    ch.onopen = function()
    {
        dlog('ch.onopen');
    };
    ch.onmessage = function(e)
    {
        dlog(e.data);
    };
    ch.onclose = function(e)
    {
        dlog('closed');
    };
    ch.onerror = function(e)
    {
        dlog('error');
    };
};

var msgSend = function(msg)
{
    ch.send(msg);
}



var offerCreate = function()
{
    peerCon
        .createOffer(function(description)
        {
            peerCon
                .setLocalDescription(description, function()
                {
                    //wait for complete of peerCon.onicecandidate
                }, error);
        }, error);
};

var answerCreate = function(descreption)
{
    peerCon
        .setRemoteDescription(descreption, function()
        {
            peerCon
                .createAnswer(
                    function(description)
                    {
                        peerCon
                            .setLocalDescription(description, function()
                            {
                                //wait for complete of peerCon.onicecandidate
                            }, error);
                    }, error);
        }, error);
};
var answerGet = function(description)
{
    peerCon.setRemoteDescription(description, function()
    { //
        console.log(JSON.stringify(description));
        dlog('local-remote-setDescriptions complete!');
    }, error);
};

var error = function(e)
{
    console.log(e);
};

var dlog = function(msg)
{
    var content = $('#onmsg')
        .html();
    $('#onmsg')
        .html(content + msg + '<br>');
}
```

- Firefox(26.0):
  `RtpDataChannels` 
  `onopen` event is fired successfully, but `send` fails.
- Chrome(31.0):
  `RtpDataChannels` 
  `onopen` event is fired successfully, and `send` also succeeded.

A SDP object by Chrome is as follows:

`{"sdp":".................. cname:L5dftYw3P3clhLve
\r\
na=ssrc:2410443476 msid:ch1 ch1
\r\
na=ssrc:2410443476 mslabel:ch1
\r\
na=ssrc:2410443476 label:ch1
\r\n","type":"offer"}`

where the **ch1** information defined in the code;

```
 ch = peerCon.createDataChannel(
            'ch1',
            {
                reliable: false
            });
```

is bundled properly.

However, a SDP object (local description) by Firefox does not contain DataChannel at all, and moreover, the SDP is much shorter than Chrome, and less information bundled.

What do I miss?

Probably, I guess the reason that `send` fails on DataChannel is due to this lack of information in the SDP object by firefox.

How could I fix this?
I investigated sources of various working libraries, such as peerJS, easyRTC, simpleWebRTC, but cannot figure out the reason.

Any suggestion and recommendation to read is appreciated.

Comment: Any progress after our chatty conversation ? I gotta go for a few days. I come back with you after xMass. Greetings to you.

Comment: Thanks Millche, Greetings to you, too. Actually, this study is for P2P voIP for mobile. FF incompatibility does not matter very much, in fact, but I wanted to be share what's going one. Having said that, I shall leave this for a while and switch to study SIP instead of webRTC.

Comment: Well, if you're the first to publish a 'ready to use cross-everything' plugin, i want to know.

Comment: I started working on this too. I am curious if you have any results!

Answer (score 1):

**[not an answer, yet]**

I leave this here just trying to help you. I am not much of a WebRTC developer. But, curious i am, this quite new and verry interresting for me.

[Have you seen this](http://www.webrtc.org/firefox) ?

> DataChannels
>
> Supported in Firefox today, you can use DataChannels to send peer-to-peer
> information during an audio/video call.  There is
> currently a bug that requires developers to set up some sort of
> audio/video stream (even a “fake” one) in order to initiate a
> DataChannel, but we will soon be fixing that.

Also, [i found this bug hook](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=837035), witch seems to be related.

One last point, **your version of adapter.js** is different from the one served on code.google. And .. alot. the webrtcDetectedVersion part is missing in yours.

https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/stable/samples/js/base/adapter.js

Try that, come back to me with good newz. ?

---

After last updating, i have this line in console after clicking 'get answer'

> Object { name="INVALID_STATE", message="Cannot set remote offer in
> state HAVE_LOCAL_OFFER", **exposedProps**={...}, more...}

but this might be useless info ence i copy pasted the same browser offre to answer.

.. witch made me notice you are using jQuery v1.7.1 jquery.com.

Try updating jQuery (*before i kill a kitten*), and in the meantime, try make sure you use all updated versions of scripts.

---

Woups, after fast reading this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/WebRTC/WebRTC_basics then comparing your javascripts, i see no SHIM.

> Shims
>
> As you can imagine, with such an early API, you must use the browser
> prefixes and shim it to a common variable.

```
> var PeerConnection = window.mozRTCPeerConnection ||
> window.webkitRTCPeerConnection; var IceCandidate =
> window.mozRTCIceCandidate || window.RTCIceCandidate; var
> SessionDescription = window.mozRTCSessionDescription ||
> window.RTCSessionDescription; navigator.getUserMedia =
> navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
> navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
```

Comment: Thanks, Milche. I have noticed this bug. In fact, I've heard this bug is fixed in FF-NigtlyBuild, so I tried my test-page http://webrtcdevelop.appspot.com/ , and the result is the same. So I must conclude this bug is nothing to do with the reason my test-code does not work so far.

Comment: i just did the same, with same results.

Comment: Great to hear you confirm the same result. Confirmation is always good :), anyway, the reason is somewhere else.

Comment: @KenOKABE Try updating adapter.js, it's different from https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/stable/samples/js/base/adapter.js

Comment: @ Milche Patern
 Thanks for letting me notice that. However, the result is the same as before. Not working with FF nightly with the latest adapter.js. I updated my test site, and please confirm that.

Comment: @KenOKABE From Firefox : local-remote-setDescriptions complete!  bot no mention about the ch.open.

Comment: ch.open event is fired in both Chrome and FF(even non-nightly) at the point of this Question posted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43721/discussion-between-milche-patern-and-ken-okabe)